# Does copy and update for immutable record types in F# share or copy memory?

Tags: .net, f#, functional-programming

Does the copy and update procedure for immutable records in F# share or copy memory?  Meaning, in the following code

```ml
type MyRecord = {
    X: int;
    Y: int;
    Z: int 
    }

let myRecord1 = { X = 1; Y = 2; Z = 3; }
let myRecord2 = { myRecord1 with Y = 100; Z = 2 }
```

do `myRecord1` and `myRecord2` share memory for the variable `X`?  More generally, is there a good reference that denotes exactly which immutable/persistent data structures in F# actively share memory?

Comment: Do you care only when X is an `int` or if it is a class type?

Comment: Memory for a value type cannot be shared unless it's boxed. Objects of reference type, however, will be shared. This goes for all of .Net, not just F#.

Comment: @JohnPalmer In general, I'm interested in more than just `int`s.  For example, I may have an array or perhaps a different class.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this case, the memory for variable `X` will be copied. The last line of your code is really just another way of writing this:

```
let myRecord2 = { X = myRecord1.X; Y = 100; Z = 2 }
```

Now, if `X` was of a reference type, the memory for reference to it would have been copied, but the memory for its contents would have been shared.

For example, consider this:

```
type MyX = { W: int; U: int }
type MyRecord = {
    X: MyX;
    Y: int;
    Z: int 
    }

let myRecord1 = { X =  { W = 5; U = 6 }; Y = 2; Z = 3; }
let myRecord2 = { myRecord1 with Y = 100; Z = 2 }
```

In the above code, the memory for `X` will be copied, but memory for `W` and `U`  will be shared.

Comment: What's the easiest way to determine whether something is a reference type or a value type?  For example, I didn't know that an immutable record would be considered a reference type.

Comment: Basically, a class is a reference type, and a struct is a value type.

Comment: @YotaXP Yes.  At the same time, an immutable record looks more like a struct and evidently it's a reference type.

Comment: In general, the rule of thumb is this: anything composite is a reference type, unless explicitly declared value type. To declare value type in F#, mark it with `[<Struct>]`. I understand the emotional impulse to have immutable types represented by structs, because they are somehow more "rigid" and "lightweight", but this is actually counterproductive if you think about it: if you know that the type is immutable, it only makes sense to keep one copy of it and only pass around references to that copy.